# can we add inheritance syntax in class extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

can we add inheritance syntax in class extension (the .m file) like:

@interface BNRItemsViewController : UITableViewController

if so, should we put () or not? is the same true for protocols? please give some example

Comment: What happens when you try it?  In general, with questions of this sort, empirical evidence is the best answer.  If you can't get the compiler to accept it, and you can't find anything in the language spec/documentation to suggest how to accomplish it, you probably can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Class extensions cannot add or change the inheritance chain.  This makes a lot of sense when you consider that Objective-C only supports single-inheritance.

Protocols can inherit from other protocols, and the syntax is the same as for class inheritance.  You still don't get any form of multiple-inheritance.